# Target any element of the elementsByClassName array?

Tags: javascript

I have a page which renders many divs of the same class name;

Is something like this possible without loop?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className of divs');
elements[*].onclick = function(){
    alert('I can click any of the divs now!');
};
```

*=any number

Comment: Yes, it's possible, did you try it

Comment: There are ways to apply a function to all elements in a javascript array. You won't get better than that

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Comment: Look into "event delegation"

Comment: @j08691 That is NOT what the OP is asking. "*Is something like this possible without loop?*"

Comment: @epascarello - oh no? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? If you want to target a single element in your collection, then you can index it. So `elements[2]` would target the 3rd element (because the array is 0-based). If you want to do something with every member of a collection, then you will loop. There are more concise ways of writing a loop (e.g. `forEach`), but you won't find anything that'll be better than `O(n)` because you still have to touch every element.

Comment: I don't want to target any particular element. I want to literally place an irregular expression instead of a number so any of the divs of that class name are under the 'onclick' function. I tried with '*' but it raises the error in the comment abov

Comment: OP what to add click events to all elements without looping.

Comment: I meant that is it required to target all the elements individually to add them the event to them or if there was a way of going around it. It;s now clear u have to loop through the array and attach the event one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an event handler to each of the elements, then you need to access each of the elements and apply the event handler in turn. For this you must use a loop (or something loop-like such as `map` (note that since `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, not an array, it doesn't have a native map function).

Your other option is to use event delegation (where you put the event handler on an ancestor element, and then examine `event.target` and test for the class membership at event time instead of bind time).

Comment: Specifically, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList` ;)

Comment: @Oriol – Indeed, although I'm surprised that when I poke at the spec, HTMLCollection doesn't seem to be defined in terms of NodeList. (I was just skimming it though).

Answer (score 3):

A short and sweet way...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className of divs');

[].forEach.call(elements, function(e){
     e.onclick = function(){
        alert('I can click any of the divs now!');
        };
});
```

Comment: I gave u a +1 but validated the first answer because i wasn't having a syntax as much as a lack of documentation problem. But thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I missed that in my answer. I will try to be more descriptive. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @void - Would this work on IE as well? I don't have access to windows right now.